# Does using certain regex sometimes conflict with certain methods?

Tags: regex

Doing some work with palindromes Javascript.  Oh yeah fun.  In know.  But wanted to ask if you use this code:

```
newString = str.replace(/[\W_]+/gi, '').toLowerCase();
```

versus this code(removing case insensitive):

```
newString = str.replace((/[\W_]+/g, '').toLowerCase();
```

Why does the 2nd code work while the 1st line of code does not?  Because, I was able to getting the same output, yet when I checked newString against the same reversed string, I was unable to get anything but true even if the string was not a true palindrome.

Comment: Don't you suppose that the answer to the question might depend on the language in which your code is written?  And perhaps also on the type and / or value of `str`?  Tag the question with the appropriate language, and provide an example complete enough to demonstrate the behavior.

Comment: I assume your input string has asymmetric casing, and your string equivalence test method is case sensitive.

Comment: Please provide the full code, complete with main() that prints both strings and the result of comparison. Better yet, use a debugger.

Comment: Please post your example `str` with which you get different results.

Answer (score 0):

In [javascript](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) /i it means case-insensitive replacement

> Example
>
> var str = "Mr Blue has a blue house and a blue car";
>
> var res = str.replace(/blue/gi, "red");
>
> The result of res will be:
>
> Mr red has a red house and a red car